# How to set default avatar for users in Sonata?

Tags: php, symfony, php-7, sonata

I wonder how to add an default avatar for users, I was searching in a documentation but I don't know Where to add a line default_avatar. I've tried in sonata_user.yml but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [advanced configuration](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/master/doc/reference/advanced_configuration.html) page, the key for the value is:

```
sonata_user:
    profile:
        # Default avatar displayed if user doesn't have one
        default_avatar: 'bundles/sonatauser/default_avatar.png'
```

There will be a lot more configuration under and around the `sonata_user:` configuration key in the config.yml file (or a file that is eventually included from there).